# Swift: Animate expanding rows in a UITableView?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, jquery-animate, heightforrowatindexpath

I currently have a UITableView with a row returning 0.0 which then expands when the user taps a "show more"-button. When that happens, the row above returns a certain value depending of the height of the container, which happens immediately. What I would like to do is to create some sort of animation of it while being extended/decreased.

Here's my code at the moment:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == 2 && self.numberOfElements >= 2 {
        if detailsVisible == false {
            self.showMoreLabel.text = "Show more (\(self.numberOfElements - 1))"
            return 0.0
        }
        else {
            self.showMoreLabel.text = "Show less"
            return embedKonteringHeight
        }
    }
}
```

Where **var detailsVisible** returns a bool if the expandable content is displayed or not.

Is there a simple way animating this? I was thinking something like a simple counter increasing/decreasing which is returned by **heightForRowAtIndexPath** within an interval.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so after some research I found out a method which works extremely well. I'll post it here in case some one wants to know the answer.

In **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**, I just needed to replace

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

with

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```